# How to express possessive

Tags: possessives

If my pie is hot, and Lola's pie is hot.  Can I say

> "*Lola and my's pies are hot*"?

Or should it be

> "Lola's and my pies are hot"?

These posts, ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) and [Yours vs. your's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/yours-vs-yours) deal with possessive pronouns and the Saxon genitive, but do not address specifically the case illustrated here.

Comment: '... only one is accepted as a standard; namely, "my wife's and my" ' (Kosmonaut).

Comment: How can you possibly think that "My's pies" is grammatical? Likewise, if someone were to write: "Your's house is number 10", "His's house is number 10"  and "Our's house..." we would all agree that it is not English. I thought you were a native speaker. Aren't you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes, I'm a native speaker. It's just that I found myself saying Lola and my's pies... and it jarred. That's why I posted my question. The 'duplicate', which I have read, doesn't appear to address this specific usage - possessive pronouns taking a Saxon genitive. Your scornful rhetorical question (My's pies!?) quotes my sample phrase partially, which misses the whole point. And your example should read something like John's house is number 10; Your house is number 10; Both John and yours' houses are number 10. Have you never heard a native speak this way?

Comment: But if you agree that "His's house is..." is ungrammatical, then it follows that a longer sentence such as: "Alice and John live next door to each other. Alice's house is No.11 while his's house is number 10" is odd. P.S I didn't vote for the duplicate but for lack of research. PPS If I sounded scornful, it wasn't meant to be. It was meant to sound incredulous, amazed and bewildered.

Comment: Related: [Yours vs. your's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/yours-vs-yours) and [Correct usage of possessive personal pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347417/correct-usage-of-possessive-personal-pronouns) and [What possessive pronouns do have an apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51746/what-possessive-pronouns-do-have-an-apostrophe)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "*His's house is...*" misses the point, which is explained in Kosmonaut's answer.  It's the *phrase* that gets the Saxon genitive.

Comment: So, does the older question "get the point" and answer your question? And it's convenient that you ignore the longer genitive sentence which I included. But here is an amended version "Alice and his's house..."  Are you still confused about the legitimacy of "Lola and my's pies..."?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The OP first version is not standard, but can be argued for on the basis that the whole phrase is having a Saxon genitive attached -  *Both-John-and-your*'s houses..., *Alice-and-his*'s house..., *Lola-and-my*'s pies... .

Comment: ...although I have understood from the reaction here that speaking this way is regarded by some as "sub-literate" (thanks for the links @Mari-LouA).

Comment: *Both Lola's pie and mine are hot.*

Comment: @PeterShor - Yes.  The trouble is, in the heat of the moment, I'd already started saying "*Lola's and my* ...".  At that point I simply wanted to get to the end of the idea.  And what came out, unplanned (obviously) was my first version.  Clearly sub-literate!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is certainly ungrammatical. The second version is much better, although it still sounds clumsy. It's a downside of the way possessives work in English and anyone wishing their writing to sound elegant would be better finding a different way to express it, eg:

- Lola's pie is hot and so is mine.
- Lola and I each have a pie and they are both hot.
- Lola's pie is hot like mine.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is ungrammatical. These are better alternatives:

> Both Lola's pie and my pie are hot.
>
> Lola's pie is hot, so is mine.